# rbing undefined method web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bing-api

I am running rails 4 with the rbing gem installed (version 1.1.0)

```
require 'rbing'
bing = RBing.new("YOURAPPID")

rsp = bing.web("ruby", :site => "github.com")
puts rsp.web.results[0].url
```

Just like the example here:
https://github.com/mikedemers/rbing

when I run it I get this error:

> undefined method `web' for # RBing::ResponseData:0x007f42500bb190

Comment: Do you set a real app id in bing = RBing.new("YOURAPPID") ? I think you should replace YOURAPPID with a real id :)

Comment: I use a real app id, but I wasn't going to post it in the forum. Thanks for looking into this though. I got my app id from here - www.bing.com/developers/createapp.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using google instead

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:authorization => nil)

google_search = client.discovered_api('customsearch', 'v1')

google_result = client.execute(
        :api_method => google_search.cse.list,
        :authenticated => false,
        :parameters => {
          'q' => query,
          'key' => key, # your key received from google
          'siteSearch' => query_params[1],
          'cx' => cx, # your cx code received from google
          'num' => 1
        }
      )
```